# How to preserve the unique IDs of rows when doing machine learning?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataset `X` that contains an ID column, some other features, and a target column. I am doing a classification task, and after doing the classification on the test set, I want to see which ID belongs to which class.

So, I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

X = df.drop(['ID', 'Target_Feature'], axis=1)
Y = df[['ID', 'Target_Feature']]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)
pol_ids = Y_test.ID ### Save the IDs of the test set to append to a new dataframe later

Y_train = Y_train.drop(['ID'], axis=1).values
Y_test = Y_test.drop(['ID'], axis=1).values

logReg = LogisticRegression()
logReg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
logReg.score(X_train, Y_train)

>>> 0.6300364252164744

predictions = logReg.predict(X_test)
predictions

>>> array([1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Then I do the following to construct a new dataframe with the ID column and the predictions:

```
y_pred = logReg.predict_proba(X_test)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(pol_ids)
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(y_pred[:,1])
df1['Predictions']=df2
df1['Name']=df.loc[df1.index]['Name'].values   ### This is one of the columns in the original dataframe
```

But, when I check the row in the original dataframe, `df`, for a given ID, its name is not the same in the new dataframe, `df1`. This means, most likely, that the IDs have not been correctly copied to the new dataframe.

So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your last line

```
df1['Name']=df.loc[df1.index]['Name'].values
```

After `reset_index` , the index is change, so change to

```
df1['Name']=df.loc[pol_ids.index]['Name'].values
```